# change installer properties in C# custom action

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, custom-action

How to change installer properties in my C# custom action?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To access a WiX property, such as those set with the Property element, use the 
Session object's indexer. Here is an example:

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult CustomAction1(Session session)
{
string myProperty = session["MY_PROPERTY"];
return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

Setting properties is just as easy. You'll set the value by referencing the key with the 
name of your property. Here's an example:

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult CustomAction1(Session session)
{
session["MY_PROPERTY"] = "abc";
return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

If the property doesn't exist when you set it, it will be created. Similarly, you can 
clear a property by setting its value to null. Creating or changing property values 
from a custom action doesn't stop the installer from displaying those properties in 
the install log. So, if a property holds information that ought to be hidden, you're 
better off declaring it in your WiX markup first and setting its Hidden attribute 
to yes.

```
<Property Id="MY_PROPERTY" Hidden="yes" />
```

Comment: Hi. I get an error when setting the value of the property when running the installer without elevation even tho the customaction is deferred and noimpersonate. PS: I had to defer it since I’m accessing IIS APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Only Win32 DLLs and VBScript **Immediate** actions have write access to installer properties. Any other custom action type can only receive properties through their command line or through CustomActionData.

Here is a tutorial for a C++ DLL custom action: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx

To get and set Windows Installer properties you can use [MsiGetProperty()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370134%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [MsiSetProperty()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370391%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, the answer is well intended, but only partially correct. Installer Classes (from Visual Studio) cannot access properties, as there is no marshaling or remoting of the Installer handle. However better managed custom action solutions do provide access, either through abstractions like Session["property"] or through direct P/Invoke on the Installer handle.