# How to do a custom validation of a selected installation target folder with WiX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Using `WixUI_InstallDir` I'm allowing the user to select a target directory for installing an add-in. After the user enters the directory, I would like to check if the chosen installation folder has a parent directory matching a certain name.

The folder of on the of the parents of the installation directory must be `SPECIFIED_NAME`:

```
C:/SPECIFIED_NAME/target --> okay
C:/SPECIFIED_NAME/foo/bar/target --> okay
C:/foo/bar/SPECIFIED_NAME/target --> okay

C:/Temp/target --> not okay
```

Is this possible using WiX 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with pure `WixUI_InstallDir`, you need to add extra validation of `WIXUI_INSTALLDIR` property using custom action.

1. Declare in your code new property `FOLDER_IS_OK`. It will take values okay/not okay from your example.
2. Write custom action, which will validate `WixUI_InstallDir` and write the result to `FOLDER_IS_OK`. Some information about this: [change installer properties in C# custom action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728940/change-installer-properties-in-c-sharp-custom-action)
   Something like that:

   ```
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult MyPathValidation(Session session)
    {
        string installDir = session["WIXUI_INSTALLDIR"];
        session["FOLDER_IS_OK"] = ValidateInstallDir(installDir);
        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
    public string ValidateInstallDir(string dirName)
    {
        //TODO
    }
   ```
3. Add this custom action to your code, like in Step 1 here: https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/authoring_custom_actions.html
4. In Wix source code find file WixUI_InstallDir.wxs. Copy whole element `<UI Id="WixUI_InstallDir">...</UI>` to your code. Change Id value to `MyWixUI_InstallDir` and link that one in `UIRef` element in your project.
5. Edit original block of your `MyWixUI_InstallDir`

```xml
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIValidatePath" Order="2">NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="3"><![CDATA[NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH AND WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID<>"1"]]></Publish>
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="4">WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH OR WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID="1"</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
```

To something like that:

```
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIValidatePath" Order="2">NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="DoAction" Value="MyPathValidation" Order="3">NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="4"><![CDATA[NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH AND WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID<>"1"]]></Publish>
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="5">FOLDER_IS_OK<>"okay"</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="6">WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH OR WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID="1"</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
```